# Question on Green's Theorem. (Answer should be positive).

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question: $\int_C (xy) dx + \exp(y^2) dy$ where C is the triangle with vertices: $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$.

Now applying the Green's Theorem I get: $\int_0^2\int_0^{1/2x} -xdydx$ which in the end gives me $-4/3$ while the answer is $4/3$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I got $-4/3$ also. The vector field $(0,e^{y^2})$ has a potential on the entire plane, so $\int_\gamma e^{y^2}\,dy$ over any closed curve $\gamma$ vanishes. It is clear enough that $\int_C xy\,dx$ is negative (plot the vector field!). Mind you, it may be easier to read your inner integral in the form $\int_0^{x/2}$. I may not be the only one with the habit of writing $1/(2x)$ without parens, because if I mean $(1/2)x$ I write $x/2$. Screw PEMDAS, BODMAS and all that. Of course, you are adviced to stick to your local custom :-)

Comment: Can you give me  link to any website to plotting these vector fields.

Comment: You can tinker with [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=VectorPlot&a=*C.VectorPlot-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2={x+y+%2C0}&f=VectorPlot.vectorfunction_{x+y+%2C0}&f3=x&f=VectorPlot.vectorplotvariable1\u005fx&f4=0&f=VectorPlot.vectorplotlowerrange1_0&f5=2&f=VectorPlot.vectorplotupperrange1_2&f6=y&f=VectorPlot.vectorplotvariable2\u005fy&f7=-1&f=VectorPlot.vectorplotlowerrange2_-1&f8=11&f=VectorPlot.vectorplotupperrange2_11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line integral $\int_C xy\,dx$(anticlockwise) is zero except on $(2,1)$ to $(0,0) $ so evaluates to

$$
\int_2^0 x(\frac{x}2)dx = -\frac43
$$